# Fill Data Table with image data as byte array in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, sql-server, datatable

So I have the data table filled but the column I need image data in is not working. I can see the table filled and can see it is reading the data, but not as a byte array, nor is it displaying the image.

```
public void Bindformview()
    {
        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Recipes", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            adp.Fill(dt);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                FormViewRecipes.DataSource = dt;
                FormViewRecipes.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                FormViewRecipes.DataSource = null;
                FormViewRecipes.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

And I know I need to insert this code, or something like it that pulls the data out of the db "thumbnail varbinary(MAX)" column as a byte stream, to get the byte array for the image to display properly:

```
 DataColumn column = new DataColumn("MyImage"); //Create the column.
column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Byte[]"); //Type byte[] to store image bytes.
column.AllowDBNull = true;
column.Caption = "My Image";

table.Columns.Add(column); //Add the column to the table.
```

and this:

```
 DataRow row = table.NewRow();
row["MyImage"] = <Image byte array>;
tables.Rows.Add(row);
```

But I do not need a new column or a new row as those fields are already there.
So how to I fill column "Thumbnail" in the data table, with byte array data to display and where do I do the insert of said code, before the if statement that loads the dt, in the if statement that binds the dt?

do I do it by stating the column like so:

```
dt.column.thumbnail.fill(byte[] bytes = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

and then put this in to fill the formview image1 ID like so?

```
                    string strBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
                    formviewrecipes.Image1.ImageUrl = "data:Image/png;base64," + strBase64;
```

I am just at a standstill and not sure how to do this.
So to be clear, I already have the DB with the Proper image info, and can display it by `<asp:image id=image1...etc />`, with other code that retrieves the image outside of the formview using this code,

```
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetImageByID", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    SqlParameter paramId = new SqlParameter()
                    {
                        ParameterName = "@Id",
                        Value = Request.QueryString["Id"]
                    };
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramId);
                    con.Open();
                    byte[] bytes = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                    string strBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
                    Image1.ImageUrl = "data:Image/png;base64," + strBase64;
                }
            }
```

but it doesn't work in a `<asp:FormView...etc/>` and I need to be able to have it do so for page formating.
This is why I was going in this direction, of using a Data Table right now. If you have a better solution I am open to trying it, as long as it can be used inside of the `<asp:formview />` element. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out:

I Needed to add an `Object o;` and this line after the databind `o = dt.Rows[0]["RecipeId"];`

Like So:

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    FormViewRecipes.DataSource = dt;
                    FormViewRecipes.DataBind();
                    //lblDataTable.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString(); ---Used for testing-
                    o = dt.Rows[0]["RecipeId"];

                }
                else
                {
                    FormViewRecipes.DataSource = null;
                    FormViewRecipes.DataBind();
                }
            }
```

and made the call to load the image as so:

```
 string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("RETRIEVE_RECIPE", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlParameter paramId = new SqlParameter()
                {
                    ParameterName = "@RecipeId",
                    Value = o //Object from the datatable

            };
                cmd.Parameters.Add(paramId);
                con.Open();
                byte[] bytes = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                if (bytes != null)
                {
                    string strBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
                    Image1.ImageUrl = "data:Image/png;base64," + strBase64;
                }
                else
                {
                    Image1.ImageUrl = "~/images/NoImageAvail.jpg";
                }
            }
```

Here is the code below if anyone else needs to do the same thing. I will be putting together a for/while or for/next for going through multiple data base entries to display at the same time instead of one at a time currently in this `<asp:forview...></formview>` element setup.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace DB_Test1
{
    public partial class Search_Results_1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string b;
        Object o;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["Search"] != null)
            {
                if (Request.QueryString["Text"] != null)
                {
                    string a = Request.QueryString["Text"];
                    b = a;
                    recipeSearch(a);
                }
            }
        }
        protected void recipeSearch(string a)
        {
            //Search the database
            con.Open();
            try
            {
                SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Recipes WHERE Type LIKE '%" + a + "%'", con);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                adp.Fill(dt);

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    FormViewRecipes.DataSource = dt;
                    FormViewRecipes.DataBind();
                    //lblDataTable.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString(); ---Used for testing-
                    o = dt.Rows[0]["RecipeId"];

                }
                else
                {
                    FormViewRecipes.DataSource = null;
                    FormViewRecipes.DataBind();
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //throw new ApplicationException("operation failed!", ex);
            }
            con.Close();
            FormViewRecipes.Visible = true;

            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("RETRIEVE_RECIPE", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlParameter paramId = new SqlParameter()
                {
                    ParameterName = "@RecipeId",
                    Value = o //Object from the datatable

            };
                cmd.Parameters.Add(paramId);
                con.Open();
                byte[] bytes = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                if (bytes != null)
                {
                    string strBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
                    Image1.ImageUrl = "data:Image/png;base64," + strBase64;
                }
                else
                {
                    Image1.ImageUrl = "~/images/NoImageAvail.jpg";
                }
            }

            Image1.Visible = true;


        }
        protected void FormViewRecipes_PageIndexChanging(object sender, FormViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            string a = b;
            FormViewRecipes.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            recipeSearch(a);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the ASPX page code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" visable="false" Height="150px" Width="150px"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:FormView ID="FormViewRecipes" runat="server" DataKeyNames="RecipeId" AllowPaging="True"
            onpageindexchanging="FormViewRecipes_PageIndexChanging" Visible="false">
             <%--<FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />--%>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <table style="border:1px solid #c1c1c1;">
            <tr style="background-color:white;font-weight:bold"><td><%--Recipe Detail--%></td><td>
                <%--<asp:Image id="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Thumbnail") %>' 
                   AlternateText='<%# Eval("ThumbnailAltTxt") %>' 
                    Height="100px" Width="100px" />--%></td>
            </tr>
              <tr><td><b>Title:- </b></td><td>
                  <asp:Label ID="lblRecipeTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>'></asp:Label></td></tr>
              <tr><td><b>Ingredients:- </b></td><td>
                  <asp:Label ID="lblIngredients" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Ingredients") %>'></asp:Label></td></tr>                
              <tr><td><b>Directions:- </b></td><td>
                  <asp:Label ID="lblDirections" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Directions") %>'></asp:Label></td></tr>
                <tr><td><b>Notes:- </b></td><td>
                  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Notes") %>'></asp:Label></td></tr>

                            </table>
            </ItemTemplate>
              <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <table style="border:1px solid #c1c1c1;">
            <tr style="background-color:#E5E5FE;font-weight:bold"><td><b>Recipe</b></td></tr>
            <tr><td><b>Recipe Title:-</b></td><td style="color:Red;">No Records Aviable!</td></tr>
            <tr><td><b>Recipe Ingredients:-</b></td><td style="color:Red;">No Records Aviable!</td></tr>
            <tr><td><b>Recipe Directions:-</b></td><td style="color:Red;">No Records Aviable!</td></tr>

            </table>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>




            </asp:FormView>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>Ad Space</p>
            <asp:Label ID="lblDataTable" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

Just remember I commented out the `<asp:image..../a>` element field that is in the `<Asp:formview.../>` element and reset my page layout to get how I wanted it to look for testing.

Comment: Also if you want to have this work and display all items you needto change the connection string to ("Select * From DB", con) and o=dt.row[0],["RecipeId"] to "o = FormViewArticles.DataKey.Value;" - Which allows you to cycle through your items in the dt, and not only grab the first item in the dt every time you go and get the image for the corresponding article. In fact I would use the "o = FormViewArticles.DataKey.Value;" from the start. Just a little tweaking.